# Force SQLDev to read more rows than it seems to be. SQL Dev, Win7 Ult 64

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

TIA for and help/advice. This is coursework so pointers to further reading would be great!

Basically I have built and normalised a db concerning a transport company and various things like driver details, trip and package details.

Trying to find those drivers who've spent more than 100 days out in 6 months. Luckily the sample data only concerns 6 months so...

I have this which works, kind of. The max result given is 27 and I can see on the data that it should be much more, so I'm wondering have I unintentionally limited SQLDev's read size? Say maybe limited it to only return from the first 100 rows or something?

```
 SELECT  driver_first_name, driver_second_name,sum(duration)
from trips 
group by  driver_first_name, driver_second_name, duration
order by sum(duration) desc
```

Thanks for your help sufleR!

```
trip_id   start_date  end_date    duration    driver_first_name  driver_second_name
1234      1/1/12     1/5/12       4             Ahmed                  Leer
```

That's a sample row, so duration is how long they were on a trip for. So I need to count up all the durations against a drivers name, then sort the results in descending order.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Remove duration from group by and check result

Comment: Actually a more believable result but still lower than expected. I think I added duration in group by because I was getting weird Group By vendor codes. Obviously went overboard with it! So my highest result is now 62

Comment: you should put a structure and sample data for this table. Is there a driver id or some unique key for driver? Firstname and surname are not unique together in real world, usually. What duration means exactly?

Comment: Should've also said, there is a unique driver_id but it's in another table and I didn't really see the point of joining for this query.